# Inline implemented interface indentation

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, indentation

I've noticed that when I inline implement an interface in the class body itself, ie. not inside a method,

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {    

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
};
```

and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (automatically fixes indentation), eclipse indents the methods *alot* like:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               // do something
                            }
};
```

Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Yes, the default formatter does not suit everyone's tastes.

Comment: Either of these answers acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your eclipse settings. You can change the default formatting by clicking: window > preferences > java > code style > formatter.

Comment: which one? You can select from a dropdown which is default formatting - in your case the default will be Eclipse formatting[built-in].

Answer (score 6):

Uncheck the "Align fields in columns" from the first tab of the Formatter

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse preferences, go to the formatter page (Window->Preferences, Java->Code Style->Formatter).  Edit the formatting 'Profile'.  Go to the 'Blank Lines' tab, and change the 'Before first declaration' value from 1 to 0.

FYI, this will change the formatting for ALL classes, not just anonymous ones.  It'd be nice if it was more granular, but there it is.